# Apache rewrite to other directory, if file exists there

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, exists

My directories look like this:

```
/assets
  /images
    /2011
    /2012
  /images-hq
    /2011
    /2012
```

In the html file every image has a tag like:

```
<img src="/assets/images/2012/example.jpg" />
```

I want to check, if the same image exists in the images-hq folder, and if it is there, i want to send that image to the user.

Example:

```
/assets/images/2012/example.jpg to /assets/images-hq/2012/example.jpg
```

**IF** /assets/images-hq/2012/example.jpg exists, if not, just serve the original.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried doing this and seems to work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (.*)/[a-z]+/(.+)\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$
RewriteCond %1/images-hq/%2.%3 -f
RewriteRule (.*)/[a-z]+/(.+)\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$ %1/images-hq/%2.%3 [L]
```

I based on [this solution](http://undefinedbehavior.net/2012/03/27/retina-rewrite/)